# Process Memory Usage by pywin32

Tags: windows, python-2.7, winapi, process, pywin32

Im trying to get a Memory Usage of a specific process.

I've found this code:

```
"""Functions for getting memory usage of Windows processes."""

__all__ = ['get_current_process', 'get_memory_info', 'get_memory_usage']

import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

GetCurrentProcess = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetCurrentProcess
GetCurrentProcess.argtypes = []
GetCurrentProcess.restype = wintypes.HANDLE

SIZE_T = ctypes.c_size_t

class PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cb', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('PageFaultCount', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('PeakWorkingSetSize', SIZE_T),
        ('WorkingSetSize', SIZE_T),
        ('QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage', SIZE_T),
        ('QuotaPagedPoolUsage', SIZE_T),
        ('QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage', SIZE_T),
        ('QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage', SIZE_T),
        ('PagefileUsage', SIZE_T),
        ('PeakPagefileUsage', SIZE_T),
        ('PrivateUsage', SIZE_T),
    ]

GetProcessMemoryInfo = ctypes.windll.psapi.GetProcessMemoryInfo
GetProcessMemoryInfo.argtypes = [
    wintypes.HANDLE,
    ctypes.POINTER(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX),
    wintypes.DWORD,
]
GetProcessMemoryInfo.restype = wintypes.BOOL

def get_current_process():
    """Return handle to current process."""
    return GetCurrentProcess()

def get_memory_info(process=None):
    """Return Win32 process memory counters structure as a dict."""
    if process is None:
        process = get_current_process()
    counters = PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX()
    ret = GetProcessMemoryInfo(process, ctypes.byref(counters),
                               ctypes.sizeof(counters))
    if not ret:
        raise ctypes.WinError()
    info = dict((name, getattr(counters, name))
                for name, _ in counters._fields_)
    return info

def get_memory_usage(process=None):
    """Return this process's memory usage in bytes."""
    info = get_memory_info(process=process)
    return info['PrivateUsage']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(get_memory_info())
```

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578513-get-memory-usage-of-windows-processes-using-getpro/

When I run it, it works without errors, but it doesn't match at all to what's 
written in the task manager.

Someone knows why it happens? why it shows me a totally different usage from the task manager?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What fields and taskmanager columns are you comparing?

Comment: @AlexK. the memory column

Comment: Which one exactly? or are you on a version of windows that just shows you "Memory" ?

Comment: @AlexK. I have windows 10 if it helps. I compare the memory column in the Details tab

Comment: @AlexK. Have you got all the information you need?

Comment: The WorkingSetSize value corresponds to the 'Working set (memory)' in Task Manager. Try turning that column on in Task Manager (right-click on the column titles). Nothing returned by that function appears to correlate to 'Memory (private working set)' though.

Comment: @AlexK. it works, but I want the private working set of the memory

Comment: So it differs from PrivateUsage?

Comment: @AlexK. can you please give me a code which instead of using GetCurrentProcess, using the OpenProcess (by a particular PID)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question is from Working set(memory) column vs Memory(active private working set) column on Task Manager.

Windows Task Manager shows only Memory (active private working set) column as default and the active private working set is *the amount of physical memory in use by the process that can't be used by other process*. To add Working set(memory) column on Task Manager, right click on column header (it will give small popup) -> Select columns -> check 'Working set (memory)' checkbox

In pywin32, win32api GetProcessMemoryInfo API provides WorkingSetSize which is the amount of physical memory currently used by the given process, but not exclusive.

Below is my python code example to retrieve the WorkingSetSize after referencing and simplifying [C++ code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/collecting-memory-usage-information-for-a-process). I didn't test the exact code posted in the above question, but I believe that would work to retrieve the WorkingSetSize info.

```
(venv) C:\>pip freeze | findstr pywin32
pywin32==300

(venv) C:\>python
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:34:34) [MSC v.1928 
32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from win32api import OpenProcess, CloseHandle
>>> from win32api import GetCurrentProcessId
>>> pid = GetCurrentProcessId()
>>> pid
7448
>>> PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION =0x0400
>>> PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010
>>> hprocess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, False, pid) 
>>> from win32process import GetProcessMemoryInfo
>>> mem_info = GetProcessMemoryInfo(hprocess)
>>> CloseHandle(hprocess)
>>> mem_info
{'PageFaultCount': 3132, 'PeakWorkingSetSize': 11702272, 'WorkingSetSize': 9883648, 'QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage': 133824, 'QuotaPagedPoolUsage': 133552, 'QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage': 12336, 'QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage': 11616, 'PagefileUsage': 3727360, 'PeakPagefileUsage': 3928064
>>> mem_info['WorkingSetSize']/1024    # KB unit 
9652.0
```

The retrieved WorkingSetSize can be compared with the size obtained by get-wmiobject command runs from Windows PowerShell

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-wmiobject win32_process -Filter "ProcessId=7448"  |findstr WorkingSetSize
MaximumWorkingSetSize      : 1380
MinimumWorkingSetSize      : 200
PeakWorkingSetSize         : 11428
WorkingSetSize             : 9883648
```

Interestingly this PowerShell result brings WorkingSetSize in Byte unit but PeakWorkingSetSize in KB unit. *11702272/1024 = 11428*

Also the same WorkingSetSize value is shown on the Working set(memory) column of the Task Manager.
[image]